# Radio buttons value is not correct in the results

Tags: python

I have created a Guest Check-In Program and everything works except for my radio buttons. Whether you select "Yes" or you select "No", the program always prints "No". The conditional seems right to me, but it is obviously failing. (This is just a portion of the full program, obviously, but this is what pertains to my issue.)

```
global emails

emails = IntVar()

Radiobutton(window, text='Yes', variable = emails, value = True).grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W+E)

Radiobutton(window, text='No', variable = emails,  value = False).grid(row = 5, column = 6, sticky = W+E)

print(self.title.get(), self.firstname.get(),self.middle.get(), 
self.lastname.get(), self.street.get(), self.city.get(), self.state.get(),
self.zipcode.get(),self.birthDay.get(), self.birthMonth.get(), 
self.birthYear.get())

if emails == 1:

    print("Yes")

else:

    print("No")

print(self.reply.get(), self.comments.get())
```

I've tried an in-line conditional as well and got the same result.

Comment: Try taking out the `== 1` in the if statement. It looks like emails will either be `True` or `False`

Comment: What Python library does this use? Indicating the used library will increase your likelihood of getting an answer faster.

Comment: My version is 3.5.2

Comment: Maybe it's the variable type? You're currently putting a boolean into a tkinter integer variable and I'm not sure if that still works as 0=False, 1=True. Maybe try it with `emails = BooleanVar()` instead?

Comment: The Tk docs say that `value=` in the Radiobutton constructor must be of the same type as the control variable.  You have an IntVar control variable but boolean values.  Did you try using ints for the values?

Comment: What is value class? Could it be "0" and "1", thus 1 == "1" returns false.